# Page Expires immediately in laravel website hosted in shared host

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cpanel, laravel-7, csrf-token

I have deployed my laravel website in a shared web hosting service provider. All other pages are working except pages like login, and register pages. The pages expire immediately i click the send button. The same pages are working properly on my local website. I am using laravel-7 and vuejs

Someone help me please

Comment: You have a APP_KEY with a value in your .env?

Comment: Here is how it looks like  'APP_KEY=base64:mh58cv...IBg='

Comment: It sounds like sessions are not working, right? So how are your sessions configured? If you are using files, did you set directory permissions and other install/config steps [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#configuration)?

Comment: I am actually new to laravel, so let me find out how i configured those files...

Comment: What is your authentication method?

Comment: @Daniel I have a users model and roles model the user is authenticated when they enters correct username and password. Am not using email as username...

Comment: Yes, but what is the Method of Api Authentication. I think that you not logged correctly in your Api. You can use JWT-Auth, Token based auth, and other methods

Comment: @DanielMesa OP did not say anything about an API?